# Delete all *.jpg in folder

Tags: perl, cgi, cgi-bin

How do I delete  files within a temp folder at only have the .jpg extension.

Here is what I tried;

```
unlink("../httpdocs/Temp/*.jpg);
```

Comment: The `*` is a shell wildcard extension and will not be recognized by Perl in your context.

Comment: You could have at least tried the Perl docs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to apply the glob function to the pattern, for example:

```
unlink glob "../httpdocs/Temp/*.jpg";
```

This is covered in the [unlink](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html) and [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) docs.  Unlink itself expects a list of files to process.  The glob function will, to quote the docs:

> In list context, returns a (possibly empty) list of filename
>   expansions on the value of EXPR such as the standard Unix shell
>   /bin/csh would do.

Answer (score 5):

martin clayton has given a good answer. To give proper warnings for failed file deletions might be a good idea, however, in which case a loop is better than using the list form of `unlink`:

```
unlink or warn "$_: $!" for glob "../httpdocs/Temp/*.jpg"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.. You need to use `glob` for removing files..

```
chdir "../httpdocs/Temp"
unlink glob "*.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to operate in a while loop (scalar context) as using glob in list context can raise memory consumption, depending on number of dentries.

```
while( my $dentry = <../httpdocs/Temp/*.jpg> ) {
    unlink $dentry or die( "Couldn't delete the $dentry file: $!" );
}
```